# What to do if I made a mistake in Schengen Visa application form?

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas, applications

I am an Indian and I am an international student in Latvia. I am currently living in Latvia. My TRP (temporary residence permit) of Latvia was finished on 25th February 2020. I applied for new TRP for Latvia on 25th February from within Latvia, and the decision will come after 45 days approximately. I also had to apply for a national D Visa (Schengen visa) for Latvia (from within latvia) on the same day (25th February), in order to stay legally in Latvia till the decision of my TRP application.

In the visa application, I made a mistake. In the section where I have to give details about my University in Latvia (because the visa is for study purpose), I put my email address (instead of university email address) in the "email address of the University" field. This section is very important.

What will I do now?

Comment: Contact the office where you applied at.

Answer (score 1):

You should contact the office at which you applied (in your case the migration department office of Latvia), their phone number is:

> +371 67209400

You can tell them you made a mistake and ask them to change it, I’m sure they’ll understand.

Comment: Why are you "sure they'll understand?" That would be reasonable, I agree, but lots of things are unreasonable. Have you dealt with them yourself?